# ESQL does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-sql

I am working on a WCF, Entity Framework, Self track solution.

I have a problem with the ESQL.

```
string cmd = "Select h.achAccId, p.patDOBirth, p.patGender from PatientEntities.AccBases as a, PatientEntities.AccHosps as h, PatientEntities.Patients as p Where h.achAccID = 57348 and p.patPatId = a.acbPatId and h.achAccId = a.acbAccId";


ObjectQuery<dbdatarecord>queryResult = null; 

using (PatientEntities db = new PatientEntities()) PatientEntities is ObjectContext  
{  
    `queryResult = db.CreateQuery<dbdatarecord>(cmd);`  
}

if ((queryResult != null) && (queryResult.Count() > 0))   
{  
    `...`  
}
```

`queryResult.Count()` causes an error : "'achAccID' is not a member of type 'PatientModel.AccHosp' in the currently loaded schemas"

I found under `PatientModel.edmx` file, under `<EntityType Name="AccHosp">` there is `<property Name="achAccID" Nullable="false" Type="int">`

So what is the real problem?

Comment: Any sprcific reason why you need to use ESQL as opposed to Linq?

Comment: I think names are case sensitive, so `h.achAccID` should probably be `h.achAccId` as seen at the end of sql sentence.

Comment: I have checked that, it is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESQL has no problem. The datacontext need refreshing. ie. db.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, db.AccHosps);